# Losing transparent background when downloading an external PNG image

Tags: android, image, png, bitmapfactory

I'm displaying an external image in an image view by fist downloading it like this:

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent());
```

Then setting this bitmap to the `ImageView` like this:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

This works all good except that one of the images is a PNG and I lose the transparent background when using the `BitmapFactory`.

Can anyone tell me how I can keep the transparent background?

Comment: Did you find any solution i will face as like same problem. Have you any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if this will help, but try following this advice and adding Options to make sure that your image is pulled in as ARGB_8888

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String, android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)